# How to remove hardcoded references from my LWC HTML

Tags: html

My LWC's HTML component (as well as email template) refernces a lot of hardcoded links. Those links are specific to the sandbox. For example:

```
<tr><img src="https:www.mysandboxname.naxx.com"></tr>
```

I will have to change this url depending on the sandbox/org. It is hardcoded and is generally not best practice. How do i remove this hardcoded link so that i can deploy this to whatever org and it wont break?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Import the resource URL, and you can use it directly:

```
import RESOURCE_NAME from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/someResource'
```

...

```
get resourceUrl() {
  return RESOURCE_NAME
}
```

...

```
<img src={resourceUrl} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have many options.

1. Custom Label.
2. Custom Metadata. (Requires Query)
3. Custom Settings. (Requires Query)

My preferred way would be to use org dependent custom metadata, as you can create all org dependent custom metadata and deploy at once as part of your deployment process.

Comment: how would the code change in lwc to take advantage of custom metadata in lwc? would i have to query using apex? @nagendra singh

Comment: Yes unfortunately you have too, Better go with label if you don't want to query.